# Detect Mute State Change on Yeti Nano?

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a [Blue Yeti Nano](https://www.bluemic.com/en-us/products/yeti-nano/) that includes a hardware mute switch. [Blue's Sherpa desktop software](https://www.bluemic.com/en-us/products/sherpa/) is able to detect mute state and pickup pattern over USB. Is there a way to detect this via shell script on Ubuntu? I am looking to trigger a script to run when the mute state is toggled.

Comment: Got rid of mine: the small USB connection on the bottom of the mic would become loose, resulting in bad contact.

Comment: No trouble here yet with my MicroUSB connection.